# space separated data into a dict

Tags: python

I'm trying to take the below output `2_YEAR_912828SR2_20120514.dat 1337045684` and create a dictionary with the name as the key and date as the value

```
#get file attributes
datadict = {}

file_list_attr = sftp.listdir_attr()
for f in (file_list_attr): 
   fname = f.filename
   fdate = f.st_mtime

   print fname, fdate
```

2_YEAR_912828SR2_20120514.dat 1337045684

Comment: Do you mean the name of the file? And the date its created?

Comment: ... and what is your **question**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example which also takes care for data conversion (timestamp --> date):

```
from datetime import date

with open("file_with_data.txt", "r") as fl:
    datadict = dict([ (file_name, date.fromtimestamp(float(timestamp))
      for line in fl.readlines() for file_name, timestamp in line.split()])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict((f.filename, f.st_mtime) for f in file_list_attr)
```

or (didn't understand q apparently) for lines with spaces:

```
dict(f.split(' ', 2) for f in file_list_attr)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is if you have `f` as an object with these attributes:

```
for f in (file_list_attr):
    datadict[f.filename] = f.st_mtime
```

That's taking your code as it is. But I think you have `f` as a string, so you would have to split it in two:

```
for f in (file_list_attr):
    filename, st_mtime = f.split(' ', 2)
    datadict[filename] = st_mtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what your code is.

```
data = {}
for file in file_list:
    data[f.filename] = f.st_mtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what you need, if you want to process the output of your code to create a dict you could make
something like this:

```
output = """2_YEAR_912828SR2_20120514.dat 1337045684
2_YEAR_912828SR2_20120515.dat 1337045684
2_YEAR_912828SR2_20120516.dat 1337045684"""

result_dict = {}
for l in output.splitlines():
    k, v = l.split()
    result_dict[k] = v
```